# Date parsing is inappropriate in python-dateutil module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dateutil

currently i'm using `python-dateutil` module v2.8.1 which is latest, here when i run something like this:

```
from dateutil import parser
print(parser.parse('May 20,2019').isoformat())
```

i got: `2020-05-20T00:00:00`

but up to `python-dateutil` module v2.4 gives results as: `2019-05-20T00:00:00`

is this a bug of that module or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything wrong - this appears to be a regression caused by adding support for parsing ISO 8601 dates such as stdlib `logging` timestamps.

```
2020-05-20 12:34:56,789
```

Numbers after the comma are millisecond portion of the time. Adding support for the comma millisecond separator also caused the bug seen in original post.

In dateutil v2.5.0+:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> parse("May 20,2019")  # bugged
datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 20, 0, 0)
>>> parse("2020-05-20 12:34:56.789")
datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 20, 12, 34, 56, 789000)
>>> parse("2020-05-20 12:34:56,789")  # working
datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 20, 12, 34, 56, 789000)
```

In dateutil v2.4.2:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> parse("May 20,2019")  # not bugged
datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 20, 0, 0)
>>> parse("2020-05-20 12:34:56.789")
datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 20, 12, 34, 56, 789000)
>>> parse("2020-05-20 12:34:56,789")  # not working
ValueError: Unknown string format
```

Note that the "2019" year in your case is just ignored. 2020 comes from replacing the current date with parsed info. If you pass in the `default` kwarg, it will replace in that instead.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> parse("May 20,1998")
datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 20, 0, 0)
>>> parse("May 20,1998", default=datetime(1998,3,19))
datetime.datetime(1998, 5, 20, 0, 0)
```

I can not find the issue mentioned anywhere on dateutil's tracker, so perhaps you should report it.